# Character development question for a god of Knowledge and Machines: How to make a god an interesting character?

Tags: roleplaying, player-characters, narrative-balance

## System

We are playing a custom system, and in the system we are all gods that create a universe, having mortals with a primary planet. The mortals are in the early iron age.

There is a rotating GM, but one main GM that has the final say. During the session, players are encouraged to take creative powers to add to the world, so decisions about what is going on are somewhat handled by players, but again final say goes to the current GM.

## Gods

There are many gods, some npc, some pc.

Each god has 2+ attributes, e.g: Fire and Honor, or Transformation and Storytelling. There are five PCs and one rotating GM. As gods level up, they may take on new attributes.

Each god has a realm, and the realms can be though of as part of the character. The gods can also create things and control them, for instance, my god has an elevator which "takes you where you want to go, unless it thinks there's somewhere else you should be". So, if the PCs use my elevator, I can choose to send them somewhere besides where they want to go.

## Threats

The threats that come up in session tend to be concerning other NPC gods, and maybe to a much milder degree PC gods. An example threat might be a trickster god stealing the aurora and requiring someone a mortal to purchase it back from him, or the god of the mortal world being in pain from the mortals digging into it, and our party has to find a way to solve the issue.

## My Character

My god is the god of Knowledge and Machines. He's similar to Will Rogers in manner, knows godly amounts of knowledge, uses machines to benefit mortals. He has buddhist master levels of patience. Nothing much threatens him really.

### My character's backstory

My character came about when the king of the gods wanted to know the answer to a riddle, and created my character.

My character helped create the planet the mortals live on. He has a realm that appears to be a serene countryside, but is really made up of machines.

Eventually, the king of the gods basically disintegrated, and my god was exposed to the timeline of a previous incarnation of the universe, before my god existed. This caused his mind to fragment into two realities and started "corrupting" him. This is where I have a few ideas, but I'm not sure how to execute them.

## Threats

The threats that come up in session tend to be concerning other NPC gods, and maybe to a much milder degree PC gods. An example threat might be a trickster god stealing the aurora and requiring someone a mortal to purchase it back from him, or the god of the mortal world being in pain from the mortals digging into it, and our party has to find a way to solve the issue.

## Question(s)

So, I guess I don't know where to go with my character. There's no real change to be had as a normal healthy god, so I introduced the corrupted aspect. I'm trying to

- How should I interact with the other god PCs in interesting ways without antagonizing them as a corrupted god?
- How can I redeem my god and bring him back to a non-corrupt state, but still leave room for growth? His original "healthy" form was too perfect and didn't have room for growth. His corrupted form is more interesting, but I feel like it can be too antagonistic.
- How can I get my god to take action? In the past he tended to be fairly passive, because he values allowing others to find their own meaning and not interfering with their quest to find meaning, even if that meant allowing them to destroy or steal something he owns. Now that he's corrupted, I'm having him get upset about things being "not perfect", and trying to "fix" them, or even just outright destroy them.

Comment: Interesting question, and in reasonable scope.

Comment: Since you're using a custom system, I'm unsure what answers to expect from a bunch of internet strangers who are unfamiliar with your system. Have you tried discussing your questions with your fellow players? What feedback did they give?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Unfortunately, I think this question is primarily opinion-based (as at least part of it is soliciting idea-generation with no way to determine a "best" answer), too broad (as it's asking 3 entirely different questions), and unclear what you're asking (since it's asking about things your character can do in a custom system about which we know very little based on your post) all at the same time... Parts of it may be answerable here with some edits, though I'm not sure how exactly to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! I'm curious what you mean by "corrupted". I'd expect it in a "going evil" or secoundary personality way, but the way you describe it makes me think more of a memory corruption angle. All of those avenues would have different answers, so can you tell us more?

Comment: I feel that this question may be best suited for the world building stack, maybe?